# Empty POST result using CodeIgniter form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone spot why my form always fails the validation?
The validation doesn't output any errors, and the POST array is always empty.
Suggests to me, its getting submitted to the wrong place but thats not the case.

```
    <form action="https://www.mydomain.com/account/withdraw" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">      <fieldset class="six-col">
        <h3>What amount?</h3>
        <span style="font-size:1.3em;position:relative;display:inline;">&pound;</span>
        <input id="amount" type="text" placeholder="1.00" style="font-size:1.3em;width:115px;background-color: transparent;color:white;"/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="six-col">
        <h3>Charges</h3>
        <span id="charges" style="font-size:1.3em;"></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="six-col">
        <h3>You leave with</h3>
        <span id="charges2" style="font-size:1.3em;"></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="six-col end-col">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn" value="Withdraw" style="width:125px;position:absolute;bottom:0" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the controller

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'Amount', 'required|xss_clean|trim|numeric|max_length[5]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {           
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $data['credit'] = $this->account_m->get_credit();
        $this->load->view('account/withdraw', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        // The withdraw code
    }
    $this->load->view('footer');
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have name set in the input..
it should be: `<input name="amount" id="amount" type="text" placeholder="1.00" style="font-size:1.3em;width:115px;background-color: transparent;color:white;"/>`

Make sure you're actually getting something back.

If at all possible to test.. echo the post var before the form_validation like so:

```
<?php echo $this->input->post('amount'); ?>
```

If you aren't getting a value back then its the form, try using `POST` instead of `post`.

If you are getting a value back then its the rule. One possibility is the `numeric` rule, try integer. Try `is_natural` or try `decimal` if you're using $0.00.

Also, use codeigniter's profiler class for development..
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

```
<?php $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); ?>
```

Comment: Good catch, didn't notice that missing `name`. +1

Comment: i always do the samething, CIs profiler is a great tool for development.. that or monitoring XHR headers via Google Chrome Developer toolkit.

Comment: damn grace period! I saw you added that (the missing name part) just while I was posting my answer :) +1 anyway

Comment: Just one of those days Mike. Sometimes you can't see it for looking. Thanks for taking the time to reply.